# Ruby-on-Rails. Problem with therubyracer (0.12.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, therubyracer

I try to execute

> `bundle i`

I get an error message:
*An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3'` succeeds before bundling.*

I try:

```
$ gem uninstall libv8
$ gem install therubyracer
```

And:

```
gem list libv8 --remote --all
gem install libv8 -v 3.16.14.19 -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir=/Users/MY_NAME/homebrew/opt/v8@3.15
```

Don't work.

I have result file **gem_make.out**:

```
current directory: /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8
/Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby- 
2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20200814-13680-i9h23c.rb extconf.rb --with-v8- 
dir\=/Users/MY_NAME/homebrew/opt/v8@3.15
checking for -lpthread... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-pthreadlib
--without-pthreadlib
/Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler                 failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:559:in `try_link'
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:777:in `try_func'
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:1004:in `block in     have_library'
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:947:in `block in checking_for'
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:946:in `checking_for'
from /Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:999:in `have_library'
from extconf.rb:3:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.5.0/therubyracer-    0.12.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you check this file? `/Users/MY_NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.5.0/therubyracer-    0.12.3/mkmf.log` the error says it should have more info about the missing libraries.

Answer (score -1):

It was helpful for me:

```
brew install ruby
brew upgrade ruby
xcode-select --install
```